# Executequeryasync in foreach loop

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, jsom

I need to store all the properties for all the users in an array. How can I achieve this, with the executequeryasync method inside my foreach loop?

```
      var profileProperties = [];
       $(userProfilesArr).each(function(index, userAccount){
            loadUserProfileProperties(userAccount)
       })
       console.log(userProfilePropArray);

    function loadUserProfileProp(userAccount){

      var userProfileProperty = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(ctx, userAccount, ["property1","property2"]);
       userProfileProperty = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(ctx).getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfileProperty);
       ctx.load(userProfileProperty);
       ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
          //profileProperties.push...
       }) 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing the foreach function - sample below:

```
var profileProperties = [];
       var i=0;
       loadUserProfileProp(userProfilesArr[i]);



    function loadUserProfileProp(userAccount){

      var userProfileProperty = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(ctx, userAccount, ["property1","property2"]);
       userProfileProperty = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(ctx).getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfileProperty);
       ctx.load(userProfileProperty);
       ctx.executeQueryAsync(function(){
          //profileProperties.push...
          if(i<=userProfilesArr.length-1){
              i=i+1;
              loadUserProfileProp(userProfilesArr[i]);
          }
          else{
              console.log(userProfilePropArray);

          }
       }) 
    }
```